# create a database in SQL Server 2014 can be mounted in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

create a database in SQL Server 2014 can be mounted in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Why don't you try it? it's trivial to create a db, copy the .mdf file, and attach elsewhere.

Comment: @MarcB, one cannot attach a database file from a later version of SQL Server to an earlier one.  The file format is different between versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DB in SQL SERVER 2014 (with data) and you want to restore in a SQL SERVER 2005 you need to "migrate" all data (tables, indexes, constraint, views, etc). A great tool to do that is Visual studio Data Tools. You can use Schema and Data Sync. It worked very well for me.